# Javascript date and time is showing wrong

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have developed a website , where end users are in Toronto . I have set timezone for them but it is showing wrong date. ahead one day from Toronto .
It shows correct time at some time but at the end of day it shows one day ahead time .. i don't know why is it doing it ?

```
function calcTime(city, offset) {

    // create Date object for current location
    d = new Date();


    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    return  nd;

}
function getdatetime() {
var date =calcTime('Toronto', '-8');


var currentDate = date.toISOString().slice(0,10);
var currentTime = date.getHours() + ':' + (date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + date.getMinutes() ; 

document.getElementById('datetime').value = (currentDate+" " + currentTime); 
}
```

Last Entries:

2020-01-16 16:44
2020-01-16 16:42

2020-01-16 16:41    //from here

2020-01-15 15:25
2020-01-15 15:23
2020-01-15 15:22

Comment: Your city variable is never used, thus "Toronto" is completely useless, only your second variable is used. But honestly, why re-create the wheel? https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: Isn't Toronto GMT-05:00?

Comment: for native code (no library required) see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString ... you can specify the timezone you want

Comment: oh, and `utc = ... whatever you are doing` ... no, dates are stored as number of milliseconds since midnight jan 1 1970 UTC ... so, `utc = d`

Comment: Can you post any failed test cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.

```js
function getdatetime() {
    let timezone =  new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Toronto"});
    let date = new Date(timezone);
    
    var currentDate = date.toISOString().slice(0,10);
    var currentTime = date.getHours() + ':' + (date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + date.getMinutes() ; 
    console.log(date);
}

getdatetime();
```